# Can we use SOUNDEX() and DIFFERENCE() for multiple words?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, spell-checking

I want to use `SOUNDEX()` and `DIFFERENCE()` functions on long sentence, containing multiple words. What I have found so far is that these two functions work on single word. For example:

```
"Stackoverflow is a very good website"
```

If I use `DIFFERENCE("Stackoverflow is a very good website")`, it will only match differences in first word of the sentence, i.e., "stackoverflow" - but not for rest of the words. I am actually trying to build an spellings suggestion query in SQL, the way google shows us correct spellings if we type in wrong.

Please help.

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @Sound1 AS VARCHAR(4)
DECLARE @Sound2 AS VARCHAR(4)
DECLARE @Equals AS BIT
DECLARE @str1 AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @str2 AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Difference AS INTEGER

SET @str1 = 'Stackoverflow is a very good website'
SET @str2 = 'Stackovxxflow'
SET @Sound1 = SOUNDEX(@str1) 
SET @Sound2 = SOUNDEX(@str2) 


IF(@Sound1 <> @Sound2)
BEGIN
    SET @Difference = DIFFERENCE(@str1, @str2)
    IF(@Difference <= 4)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 [Address] FROM _Employee
        ORDER BY DIFFERENCE([Address],@str2) DESC
    END
END
```

Comment: The behavior of the SOUNDEX() and DIFFERENCE() functions [changed in SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx); which version are you running?

Comment: Also, have you considered instead using an implementation of [Levenshtein's distance function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)? Soundex is a hash function, which can be used for measuring similarity (as in T-SQL's `DIFFERENCE()` function, which simply does a string comparison of soundex values) but which isn't inherently well suited for it; Levenshtein's function, meanwhile, gives you a scalar measurement of similarity which, being grapheme- rather than phoneme-based, will be both more accurate for, and more directly applicable to, a "did you mean..." suggestion system.

Comment: @Aaron Miller: I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: The T-SQL code above is working fine for single word, but it does not work for more than 1 words in a sentence, it only matches the first word.

Comment: Soundex only looks at the first few syllables of a given string, so I wouldn't expect it to work for a whole sentence; this seems like another good reason to use Levenshtein instead, although even that would be more usefully done word-wise than sentence-wise.